# Tensorflow: Issues with determining batch size in custom loss function during model fitting (batch size of "None")

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

I'm trying to create a custom loss function, in which I have to slice the tensors multiple times. One example is listed below:

```
# Since different nodes need different activations, I decided to just do it like this
def activations(y_true, y_pred):
    n = y_true.shape[1]
    means = tf.slice(y_pred, begin=[0,0], size=[y_pred.shape[0], n])
    stdevs = tf.slice(y_pred, begin=[0,n], size=[y_pred.shape[0], n])
    corrs = tf.slice(y_pred, begin=[0,2*n], size=[y_pred.shape[0], y_pred.shape[1]-2*n])
    stdevs = keras.activations.softplus(stdevs)
    corrs = keras.activations.tanh(corrs)
```

This (and the entire loss function) works fine when testing it manually on selfmade Tensors y_true and y_pred, but when using it inside a loss function it will give an error upon model fitting (compiling goes fine).

```
    File <filename>, line 105, in activations  *
        means = tf.slice(y_pred, begin=[0,0], size=[y_true.shape[0], n])

    TypeError: Expected int32 passed to parameter 'size' of op 'Slice', got [None, 3] of type 'list' instead. Error: Expected int32, but got None of type 'NoneType'.
```

So apparently, it can't determine the batch size when executed inside a loss layer.

How do I solve this?

(note: I'm not looking for a solution to this specific code only, since I'm slicing my tensors quite a lot. I'm looking for a general solution to slicing).

I tried to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235029/issue-of-batch-sizes-when-using-custom-loss-functions-in-keras) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71277089/tensorflow-batch-size-issue-thrown) and I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53235029/) post. Is writing a custom generator to make the batch size static really the only way to do this?

Thanks in advance?

**EDIT:**
Here's a (hugely) simplified version of the code, that triggers the error.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr

import keras
from keras import layers

import tensorflow as tf

# Since different nodes need different activations, I decided to just do it like this
def dummy_loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
    n = y_true.shape[1]
    means = tf.slice(y_pred, begin=[0,0], size=[y_pred.shape[0], n])
    stdevs = tf.slice(y_pred, begin=[0,n], size=[y_pred.shape[0], n]) #I'm assuming these are all (0, infty)
    corrs = tf.slice(y_pred, begin=[0,2*n], size=[y_pred.shape[0], y_pred.shape[1]-2*n])
    
    stdevs = keras.activations.softplus(stdevs)
    corrs = keras.activations.tanh(corrs)
    
    relErrors = tf.math.square(means - y_true)/stdevs
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(relErrors))

def dummy_model(dim):
    model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(1)),
        layers.Dense(2*dim + int(round(dim * (dim-1)/2)), kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()),
    ]
    )
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss=dummy_loss_func, optimizer="adam")
    return model

#Generating some fake data
n = 5000
dim = 3
pts = npr.uniform(size=[n, 2*dim + int(round(dim * (dim-1)/2))])
dummy_in = np.zeros(n)
print(dummy_in.size)
print(pts.size)

#Comping the model goes fine
model = dummy_model(dim)

# Model exucution will go fine
print(model.predict([0]))

# Just calling the loss function also works
print(dummy_loss_func(tf.constant([[3., 2., 1.],[1., 2., 3.]]), tf.constant([[2., 1., 1., 5., 3., 2., 3., 2., 1.], [2., 5., 1., 1., 3., 6., 3., 4., 1.]])))

# The error only comes here
model.fit(dummy_in, pts, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's work through this together.  Likely both of us will need to edit things back and forth.

I'm going to address the slice part of your question, since that was the most tractable given the information.

Let's instantiate a tensor of shape [3, 3, 3]:

```
y = tf.constant([ [[1, 2, 3]   , [4, 5, 6   ], [7, 8, 9   ]],                                                                                                          
                  [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]],                                                                                                 
                  [[19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27]] ])
```

Notice that this is `1` tensor of shape [3, 3, 3].  Let's visualize it:

```
[ins] In [50]: y[0]                                                                                                                                                         
Out[50]:                                                                                                                                                                    
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=                                                                                                                               
array([[1, 2, 3],                                                                                                                                                           
       [4, 5, 6],                                                                                                                                                           
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                            
[ins] In [51]: y[1]                                                                                                                                                         
Out[51]:                                                                                                                                                                    
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=                                                                                                                               
array([[10, 11, 12],                                                                                                                                                        
       [13, 14, 15],                                                                                                                                                        
       [16, 17, 18]], dtype=int32)>                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                            
[ins] In [52]: y[2]                                                                                                                                                         
Out[52]:                                                                                                                                                                    
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=                                                                                                                               
array([[19, 20, 21],                                                                                                                                                        
       [22, 23, 24],                                                                                                                                                        
       [25, 26, 27]], dtype=int32)>
```

In terms of axes, we can imagine the left-most axis containing 3 3x3 matrices, which we referenced above using `y[0]`, `y[1]`, and `y[2]`.  Now let's carve this cube of numbers.

```
[nav] In [53]: tf.slice(y, begin=[0, 0, 0], size=[2, 2, 2])                                                                                                                 
Out[53]:                                                                                                                                                                    
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=                                                                                                                            
array([[[ 1,  2],                                                                                                                                                           
        [ 4,  5]],                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                            
       [[10, 11],                                                                                                                                                           
        [13, 14]]], dtype=int32)>
```

What's happening here is we're asking for a smaller cube from the bigger cube, specifically of shape `[2, 2, 2]` and we want it to start from the point `[0, 0, 0]`.  So we are going to make three cuts to that bigger cube: first we're going to go into the "computer" axis two steps, so nothing from the deepest layer there should show up (numbers `[19, 20, 21],[22, 23, 24],[25, 26, 27]` in shape `[3, 3]`).  Then we are going to make a horizontal cut, which means none of the numbers from `[7, 8, 9],[16, 17, 18]` show up, `[25, 26, 27]` was already chopped off in the last cut.  Lastly, we make a vertical cut 2 steps from the origin, ensuring `[3, 6],[12,15]` don't show up. So we lose nine numbers in the first chop, we would've lost nine in the second, but three overlapped with the first chop, so we only lost six.  The third chop, we would've lost nine, but we lost three from the first chop, two from the second chop (would've been three, but one overlaps with the first), which leaves four that were lost in the last chop. `27 - (9 + 6 + 4) = 8` which is what we got.

One of the key things to work on is to ask the question: do I have a batch here, or is it one observation that's in the batch that I'm handling. How can you tell? The left-most axis is the batch axis, and it's generally represented as `None`, that means there's a variable number of batches.   Let's make a batch of the tensor we have, which you can do with the above tensor as following:

```
[ins] In [57]: tf.reshape(y, shape=(-1, 3, 3, 3))                                                                                                                           
Out[57]:                                                                                                                                                                    
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3, 3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=                                                                                                                         
array([[[[ 1,  2,  3],                                                                                                                                                      
         [ 4,  5,  6],                                                                                                                                                      
         [ 7,  8,  9]],                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                            
        [[10, 11, 12],                                                                                                                                                      
         [13, 14, 15],                                                                                                                                                      
         [16, 17, 18]],                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                            
        [[19, 20, 21],                                                                                                                                                      
         [22, 23, 24],                                                                                                                                                      
         [25, 26, 27]]]], dtype=int32)>                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                            
[ins] In [58]: tf.reshape(y, shape=(-1, 3, 3, 3)).shape                                                                                                                     
Out[58]: TensorShape([1, 3, 3, 3])
```

What the above is saying is that reshape my data so that I have a 3x3x3 cube, but I also want something in the left-most, aka batch, axis.  Since there's 27 numbers, it just "deepens" the dimensions. This can be seen by the addition of another pair of `[ ]`s in the output above.  It can't manufacture numbers for us after all as these are our observations.  You can also use `tf.expand_dims` but I find `tf.reshape` to be more intuitive.

Now we have a batch of size 1, where each observation is a cube of shape `[3, 3, 3]` which can be assigned to `y_pred` if you like. Try and run the batch through your functions and see how it works.  Another thing that I have found super helpful with dealing with issues of shape is using `ipdb` and embed mode in `ipython`.  You can set breakpoints and get into the offending lines and observe and fix.  Best of luck!

Solution (w/o any fundamental domain knowledge.  Apparently tensors are domain agnostic :) )

```
pts_tensor = tf.constant(pts)                                                                                                                                               
dummy_in_tensor = tf.constant(tf.reshape(dummy_in, (-1,1)))                                                                                                                 
my_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dummy_in_tensor, pts_tensor))                                                                                                   
model.fit(my_ds, verbose=1)
```

I think the issue was with the batch axis.  To do any better, I'd need to understand the domain, but I got some studying to do :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I followed all your steps and I do not run into any problems. Even when trying this out on my code. That's the peculiar thing about this one. When I test it on premade tensors, it works just fine. It only goes wrong when I try to use it as a loss function. Suddenly the tensor size becomes [None, 3] instead of [batch_size, 3]. The batch size may be variable, but somehow I can't get the size within the function. That also makes it really hard to debug.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible snippet of your code so I can see if I can help you?  Your code should not rely on the batch size, as from my understanding, the loss function is computed once per batch, and that batch size shouldn't influence the computation.  The batch size is a hyperparameter that influences how the learning is done, but it shouldn't be used inside the learning process itself.  See if you can come up with an artificial example that works, which represents a version of your problem, which, if solved, solves your problem itself.

Comment: Thanks for all your time! I added a code snippet to the original post that triggers the error. It also shows that the error isn't triggered when manually entering a tensor, only when training a model via that loss function. I hope this will help you replicate the problem. Btw, don't ask what the code is meant to do. I just stripped away everything until I had the bare minimum that still causes the issue.

Comment: Haven't solved it yet, but the issue is with the shape of y_pred being [None, 9], happening on line 12 of the code that autograph generates 
                                                                                                              
 12                 means = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).slice, (ag__.ld(y_pred),), dict(begin=[0, 0], size=[ag__.ld(y_pred).shape[0], ag__.ld(n)]), fscope)

Comment: The problem isn't in the loss function, it's likely in the shape the model is outputting.

Comment: This was a batch of a problem, or rather, a problem of batches.  It was an issue with the batching.  Solution in the response above as no space here.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for putting in the time to create a reproducible example and best of luck!

Comment: Just one more question, the batch size now always seems to be 1, is there any way to increase the batch size without getting the None error?

I tried adding .batch(batch_size) to the DS, but it does seem to recreate the same error.

Comment: I also wondered the same thing, but I think it would require me to understand semantics of the loss function better.  See if you can figure it out, if you're still stuck, let's work on it together in a day or so.